# How to replace condition inside if based on a value of variable

Tags: perl

How can a condition inside if block be changed based on the variable value in Perl?

Let's say if $platform value is "window", then evaluation statement of "if ()" must be different, and if $platform value is Linux, evaluation statement of "if()" must be different.

**Code Snippet:**

```
my $command;

if ( $platform eq "lnx86" ){
 $command='( $kk eq "qw" ) ';
}
else{
 $command='( $kk eq "we"  ) ';
 
}
my $kk="we";
my $platform=wint;   ## Passed from outside as a command line parameter

if ( $command ) {    ## (Line 13) Here, I want the value of $command to be replaced and if() evaluate the condition after replacement of the variable. Currently, it checks that the $command value is substituted and thus returns TRUE or FALSE. But, desire is that the value of $command must be substituted, and the substituted value must be evaluated.

 print "def\n";
}
else{
  print "nothing";
}
```

**Requirement:**

Here, ( on line 13) I want the value of $command to be replaced and if() evaluate the condition after replacement of the variable. Currently, it checks
that the $command value is substituted and thus returns TRUE or FALSE.
But, desire is that the value of $command must be substituted, and the
the substituted value must be evaluated.

Comment: Are you really trying to use string eval to compare two different strings? `$kk eq "qw"` or `$kk eq "we"`? Because that seems very trivial to the point of inane.

Comment: If the solution escapes you: `if (platform eq "lnx86") { $cmp = "qw" } else { $cmp = "we" }; if ($kk eq $cmp) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are asking.

First, in Perl, a boolean context, such as the conditional for an `if`, has specific ideas about true and false. False is `0`, `'0'`, `''`, and undef. Everything else is true. Your version of `$command` is always going to be true because it's never one of those false values.

Second, I'm not sure why you are trying to construct the conditional as a literal string. Maybe there's some other constraint that's leading you that way.

You have this:

```
if( $command ) { ... }
```

But why isn't that just:

```
if( $platform eq "lnx86" ) { ... }
```

Perhaps you want to select the thing to compare to. Have most of your expression in the `if` parens and use a variable for the thing you want to compare to:

```
my $thingy = $platform eq "lnx86" ? 'qw' : 'ew';
if( $kk eq $thingy ) { ... }
```

Is there something else going on with that string in `$command`? If so, many make that final string at the last moment but still use its components:

```
my $thingy = [ '( %s eq "we" )', $platform ];
if( $thingy->[1] eq "lnx86" ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```perl
my $expected = $platform eq "lnx86" ? "qw" : "we";
if ($kk eq $expected) { ... }
```

---

Comparisons return a value which can be stored. As such, your problem can be solved by simply replacing

```perl
my $command;
if ( $platform eq "lnx86" ) {
   $command = '( $kk eq "qw" )';
} else {
   $command = '( $kk eq "we"  )';
}

if ($command) { ... }
```

with

```perl
my $doit;
if ( $platform eq "lnx86" ) {
   $doit = $kk eq "qw";
} else{
   $doit = $kk eq "we";
}

if ($doit) { ... }
```

---

Now that we established the general principle, we can simplify the code some. `if (...) { $x = ...; } else { $x = ...; }` suggests the use the conditional operator.

```perl
my $doit = $platform eq "lnx86" ? $kk eq "qw" : $kk eq "we";
if ($doit) { ... }
```

We don't even need a variable, though I'm not sure it's a good idea to eliminate.

```perl
if ($platform eq "lnx86" ? $kk eq "qw" : $kk eq "we") { ... }
```

---

We could also take a different approach. Since we're always checking `$kk` for equality, we could instead store the value to compare against.

```perl
my $expected;
if ( $platform eq "lnx86" ) {
   $expected = "qw";
} else{
   $expected = "we";
}

if ($kk eq $expected) { ... }
```

And simplified.

```perl
my $expected = $platform eq "lnx86" ? "qw" : "we";
if ($kk eq $expected) { ... }
```

Again, we can eliminate the variable. And again, it's probably not a good idea to do so.

```perl
if ($kk eq ( $platform eq "lnx86" ? "qw" : "we" )) { ... }
```